# Liferay 6.1 TLSv1.2 is it possible?

Tags: java, tomcat7, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.1 and tomcat has jre1.6.0_20 
TLS1.2 doesn't work with 1.6 is it possible to change JRE?

Is it possible run TLS1.2 in Liferay 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [compatibility Matrix](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix), 6.1 EE is compatible with Java 8, starting from 6.1.20 GA2, which was released in August 2012. In case you're using 6.1.2 GA3, which was released in December 2013, there's a good chance that it's compatible (given that your own plugins are compatible as well). However, 6.1 CE has long reached the end of its life, and you should strongly consider to upgrade to get security fixes. You might end up with an outdated system that attackers can communicate to with strong transport layer security.

Another alternative is to use a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache httpd) as webserver to front Liferay, and you're completely free to choose its version, to support the latest and greatest cipher suites. This is probably the quickest way to bring in newer algorithms. Use the time that you win by not validating the Java8-compatibility of Liferay 6.1 CE and work on the upgrade.